# 60s/90s animated medival movie where an the main character meets an old woman who's been imprisoned since she was young and who then burns the castle

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, animated-series

I can't exactly remember the plot but I do remember a scene where an old woman who said that she has been imprisoned since she was young and beautiful and then proceeded to burn the Castle and laughing maniacally while the castle was burning and then in the next scene there was a male character who opened a secret door that was hidden behind some green flowers/bushes (maybe roses) to get away, the movie had swords and stuff in it,

EDIT: I only saw part of the movie when I was around 8 and don't remember much but I don't think that it had magic in it but I could be wrong. So the story followed a young male character (I think) who was thrown into a dungeon where he met this really old woman, then the boy was taken by the guards for interrogation or something, then the castle started burning and the old woman started giving a monologue how the castle's owner had her imprisoned since she was a young and beautiful girl and now she gets to have her revenge so she lits the castle on fire with a torch or something, and as the fire surrounds the castle we can hear the old woman laugh maniacally, then some guards of the castle go near a bush near the castle and open a secret door to get away

i've already searched and searched for this movie and so far here are two movies i can safely cross of the list: The Black Cauldron and Quest for Camelot

Comment: Did the movie have any magic systems at all? Or any fantastical beasts like Dragons or Griffins?

Comment: i saw part of the movie when i was around 8 and don't remember much but i don't think so, the story followed a male character (i think) who was thrown into a dungeon where he met this really old woman, then the boy was taken by the guards for interrogation or something, then the castle started burning and the old woman started giving a monologue how the castle's owner had her imprisoned since she was a young and beautiful girl and now she gets to have her revenge, and as the fire surrounds the castle, some guards of the castle go behind a bush near the castle and open a secret door to get away

Comment: Probably some version of Ivanhoe. See this part: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivanhoe#Capture_and_rescue   "The castle is set aflame during the assault by Ulrica, the daughter of the original lord of the castle, Lord Torquilstone, as revenge for her father's death." What was the animation like? Disney, Anime, more cartoonish? When were you 8 years old? During 90s or?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about Science Fiction or Fantasy as defined in the [help]

Comment: @fez There is some fantasy involved, because the woman, Ulrica, curses the main bad guy that he won't die a heroic death. He dies by falling into the fire and burning to death. Of course, she is the one who started the fire in the first place and thus makes it a self-fulfilling prophecy.

Comment: @jo1storm - is there actual magic involved in the curse? Or does the woman just say "I curse you to not die a heroes death"?

Comment: @fez "Now, you must pay for your crimes. I lay on you this curse. That you shall die no soldier's death. But perish like a fox in its den. There is no escape. No escape." It is left ambiguous if there is magic involved. Because, again, it is her who starts the fire. The guy replies with "Gah, witch!" then she cackles maniacally. Its at the 38, 39 minute of the film.

Comment: I always wondered about the backstory in that part of Ivanhoe.  Richard I returned to England in 1194, the Norman conquest was in 1066, and almost every single Saxon lord in England lost their land during the rebellions against William the Conqueror by 1087.  So if her Saxon father had been dispossessed and killed by Normans during the conquest or the following rebellions, Ulrica should be at least 107 years old.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The animated movie might be Ivanhoe(1986).

Captured hero? Check.

Meets an old woman who is in captivity for a long time? Check.

The old woman burns the castle during an assault, laughing maniacally? Check.

Rosebush secret passage? It happens at 44:30 minute mark.

See if this rings a bell.

Burning castle scene:
[image: burning castle scene]

Comment: i'm 99% sure that this is it, i just watched briefly the ending and it looks like this is it, i'll watch all the animated remakes but it looks like this is it, i can't thank you enough mate, i've looked for this movie for the last 8 years and i've finally found it, i even whipped out a drawing tablet to draw what i can remember

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Oh wow, this REALLY looks like the same animators from He-Man.  It's even the same haircut.